# How do I create an input spinner with dynamic values in it

Tags: javascript, laravel, input

I want to create an input spinner with dynamic values (like: 125, 180, 200, 270, 260 and so on, there is no pattern) that I have stored in my db.
For my tech stack I am using Laravel, JavaScript, HTML, CSS and Bootstrap.

I was able to get the package in a dropdown but I was unable to put those in a input spinner

```
<select class="form-select form-select-lg srd" onchange="facebookrr()" id="facebookpack" aria-label="Default select example">

     <option selected value="">Select package</option>
      @foreach ($facebook as $item)
        <option value="{{ $item->amount }}">{{ $item->amount }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

I am using Bootstrap's input spinner.

```
<input type="number" value="5" min="0" max="100" step="1">
<script>
   $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner();
</script>
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: When we fix your spelling and code, please do not roll back to your version. Instead update ours.

Comment: [Documentation](https://shaack.com/projekte/bootstrap-input-spinner/) should help

Comment: I don't think input spinner natively supports custom random values, it's more based on steps.

Comment: I don't think an input spinner is suitable to select an item from a list.

Comment: It is non-trivial. Even after looking at the documentation, assuming I have the correct plugin

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some more detail? Are you looking to create separate input spinners for each value that lets the user change those dynamic values? Or are you wanting the spinner to only step between those values?

For the first option, you should be able to just set the `value` attribute of the `input` element the same way you did the `option` elements.

```
@foreach ($facebook as $item)
    <input type="number" value="{{ $item->amount }}" step="1" min="0" max="1000" />
@endforeach
<script>
    $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner();
</script>
```

For the second option, you may have to rely on javascript. Basically, you would create the array of your desired values and then keep track of the index of the array that contains the current value of the input element. Something like:

```
// Generate the array via your Laravel code.
const vals = [];
@foreach ($facebook as $item)
    vals.push("{{ $item->amount }}");
@endforeach
// This would give an array like ['125', '180', '200', '260', '270' and so on

let oldIndex = 1;
$("input[type='number']").inputSpinner()
$('#myInput').on('input', function() 
    // get the current value of the input, which will be +1 or -1 than the value in our array
    let goalValue = $(this).val();
    let newIndex = oldIndex; // we will update this later
    if(goalValue > vals[oldIndex]) {
        newIndex++;
        // make sure the values can't go beyond what is in the array
        if(newIndex >= vals.length) newIndex = vals.length - 1;
    } else if(goalValue < vals[oldIndex]) {
        newIndex--;
        // make sure the values can't go lower than what is in the array
        if(newIndex < 0) newIndex = 0;
    }
    // update the oldIndex value with the new one
    oldIndex = newIndex;
    // set the value of the input field
    $(this).val(vals[newIndex]);
});
```

Here is a snippet of the entire code with the HTML

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-input-spinner@3.3.3/src/bootstrap-input-spinner.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="number" step="1" min="0" max="1000" id="myInput" value="1" />  
    <script>
      // Commented this part for the snippet to work; added a hard-coded array below
      /*
      const vals = [];
      @foreach ($facebook as $item)
        vals.push("{{ $item->amount }}");
      @endforeach
      // This would give an array like ['125', '180', '200', '260', '270' and so on
      */

      const vals = ['125', '180', '200', '260', '270']; // make sure numbers are in ascending order
      let oldIndex = 0;
      $("input[type='number']").inputSpinner()
      $('#myInput').on('input', function() {
        // search the array for the next closest value that matches
        let goalValue = $(this).val();
        let newIndex = oldIndex;
        if(goalValue > vals[oldIndex]) {
          newIndex++;
          if(newIndex >= vals.length) newIndex = vals.length - 1;
        } else if(goalValue < vals[oldIndex]) {
          newIndex--;
          if(newIndex < 0) newIndex = 0;  
        }
        oldIndex = newIndex;
        $(this).val(vals[newIndex]);
      });
    </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

For more help with bootstrap input spinners, see https://shaack.com/projekte/bootstrap-input-spinner/.

**UPDATE SUMMARY:** Thanks to mplungjan for the push to test the code, which prompted me to come up with a completely different answer.

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan for the push. I completely updated the answer with new logic.

Comment: Well done......